# 405 method not allowed in POSTMAN with GET (Next js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, postman, next.js13

I'm unable to get data in the postman and also in the browser. When try to access my api route in the browser they said " This page is not working, HTTP error 405 "

Here is the code for api route:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znbfY.png)

```
import { dbConnect } from "@/app/config/dbConnect";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import ProductModel from "@/app/model/addProduct";


dbConnect();

// POST Data in DataBase

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const body = await req.json();

    const newProduct = await ProductModel.create(body);

    return NextResponse.json({
      success: true,
      message: newProduct,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code == 11000) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Product Already Exist!",
      });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message.split(":")[2].trim().split(",")[0],
    });
  }
}

// To Get Data

const fecthProducts = async () => {
  try {
      var res = await axios.get("/api/products")
      
      console.log(fecthProducts);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Data is posting successfully in the database mongoDB. When I try to fetch the route in the browser it says HTTP error 405.[You can image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM1PN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to fetch GET on POST(PUT) route, for the first look.

```
export async function POST(req)
```

If this route you try to fetch you must to change method POST->GET

```
export async function GET(req)
```

or if you trying to fetch data from this route and you want to post data there also you need to describe another GET method

Comment: Can you provide the code for the GET method on my end my code is not working.

Comment: When I try to fetch data from the api postman says 405 method error..

`const fecthProducts = async () => {
  try {
      var res = await axios.get("/api/products")
      
      console.log(fecthProducts);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
  }
}`